# HEAD~1, fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD~1' ... what could I be doing wrong?

Tags: git

I've never had this problem before and google/stack seems to not have any answers on it. I've rebase and adjusted history plenty of times before, this is a new repo with a single branch (`master`) and two commits. I've omitted some personal details.

Simply, I attempted to rebase to edit commit:

```
me@~/Documents/prod (master)
$ git rebase -i HEAD~1
fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD~1'
```

odd.. so I check log:

```
me@~/Documents/prod (master)
$ git log
commit 2de7... (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: me <email>
Date:   Wed Sep 28 23:32:42 2022 -0400

    mm

commit b375...
Author: me <email>
Date:   Wed Sep 28 23:27:57 2022 -0400

    baseline with networking for multiclient movement, item pick,
```

my remote origin is correct and fine as well.

Comment: This suggests a bug in `git rebase`, which *should* allow specifying the root commit this way. VonC's suggested workaround should work though.

Comment: does `git rev-parse HEAD~1` give you a valid hash ? does `git rev-parse "HEAD~1"` (with quotes) give a different result ?

Comment: also, to better understand what `git log` shows : `git log --graph`

Answer (score 3):

Since you only have two commit, check if a `git rebase -i --root` would not work better.

That way, you avoid referencing `HEAD~1` (in your case, the first commit of the branch, commit which does not have any parent), and use the [`--root` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---root), which is made for that use case.

Comment: This solution works for me ! Had 9 commits and can access up to HEAD 8 but not the 9th. Using --root option save my day :-)